# How to bind a Combobox ItemSource to a Property not in the DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, datacontext

I have a Dialog box, ConfigSetup that has a Combobox. Its data context is set to the viewModel, but I need to bind the ItemSource of my Combobox to a property in the main window( MainWindow).

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
   ...
        public CfgData.TMicMode[] MicModeOptions
        {
            get
            {
                return (CfgData.TMicMode[])System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(CfgData.TMicMode));
            }
        }

   }
```

Here's where the viewModel is setup in the dialog box code

```
    public partial class ConfigSetup : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ConfigSetupVM vm_ = null;
        public ConfigSetup(CfgData cfgData)
        {
            vm_ = new ConfigSetupVM(cfgData);

            InitializeComponent();

            vm_.RequestClose += delegate
            {
                Close();
            };


            DataContext = vm_;

        }
   }
```

Here's the code in the VM that has the selectedvalue property to bind to

```
   class ConfigSetupVM : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
    {
    ...

         /// <summary> 
        /// C-5000's microphone mode.
        /// </summary>/
        public CfgData.TMicMode MicMode
        {
            get { return model_.MicMode; }
            set { model_.MicMode = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MicMode"); }
        }
```

Here's the XAML with the combobox

```
<Window x:Class="RpP25.ConfigSetup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:RpWin="clr-namespace:RpP25"
    Title="FCT Configuration" 
    Width="300"
    SizeToContent="Height"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=name}"
    Background="AliceBlue" >
    <Window.Resources>
    ...
    </Window.Resources>
    ...

    <ComboBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="75"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RpWin:MainWindow.MicModeOptions, Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding RpWin:MainWindow.MicMode, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=Not Selected,
                                      ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />


...
```

I know I'm missing something fundamental to Binding, but I can't for the life of figure out how to bind to something outside the datacontext.

I've tried to use FindAncestor... with no success

You help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways. The one is, as the code below, to use the static member.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.MicModeOptions} , Mode=OneWay}"/>

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public **static** CfgData.TMicMode[] MicModeOptions
    {
    }
}
```

The other is to use `Resources` in XAML, where the target class(MainWindow in your code) has to get a default constructor(parameterless).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:MainWindow x:Key="mainWindow"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainWindow}, Path=MicModeOptions , Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks,  For method 1 - Why do I have to make it static? For Method 2 - Does the new resource create additional MainWindow object, or is it a reference to the already existing instance?

Comment: As far as I know, so far, there isn't the way to link an existing instance to XAML. So, I mentioned the `static` to get reference of it.

Answer (score 0):

How is the dialog window launched? If it is launched via window.ShowDialog() then you could pass the necessary object you need to bind to as a parameter to the constructor of your dialog window. The constructor then assigns it to an internal property to which your XAML code can bind to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, easy and clean.

```
<!-- In user countrol resources -->
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Currencies}" x:Key="Currencies"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<!-- below inside ex. DataGrid -->
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Currencies}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
            DisplayMemberPath="IsoCode"
            SelectedItem="{Binding BaseCurrency}"/>

<!-- IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" is important, otherwise ComboBoxes will select same item for each child viewmodel -->
```

reference to blogpost http://kostylizm.blogspot.ru/2014/04/wpf-combobox-itemssource-bind-to-parent.html